# Unable to load freemarker template using multipartResolver

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I am using MultipartFile configured in my Spring MVC app via the classpath:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="MyController" class="myController">
        <property name="myTemplate" value="classpath:myTemplate.txt"/>

    </bean>
```

And I am trying to use freemarker in order to load this templete:

```
    public class MyController
    {
        private Resource myTemplate;

        ....

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        Template tpl = cfg.getTemplate(myTemplate.getFilename());
```

But when I run it I am getting an error: **Template classpath:myTemplate.txt not found**

I tried using: `cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(myTemplate.getFile().getParentFile())` to determine the directory but that didn't help either.

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the quoted error message I suppose `myTemplate.getFilename()` returns `classpath:myTemplate.txt`, not `myTemplate.txt`. That would exaplain why it doesn't work even if you set the template directory to `myTemplate.getFile().getParentFile()`.

But the more fundamental problem here is that you seem to misuse the FreeMarker API. The `Configuration` object should be created once in the application life cycle, normally. That's among others because it contains the template cache. If you don't use the template cache anyway, then you might as well load the template into a `String`, and create the `Template` with the `Template` class constructor. (However, if it `#include`-s or `#import`-s other templates, then for that FreeMarker will call `cfg.getTemplate` internally.) If you want to use `cfg.getTemplate` (and thus the cache too), then probably you should use a `TemplateLoader` that understands those Spring resource names, then configure FreeMarker to use that (`cfg.setTemplateLoader(yourTemplateLoader)`). I don't know if Spring already contains such thing or not, but in general it's not difficult to wrap a storage API into the `TemplateLoader` interface. (It's certainly easier and more robust on the long run than trying to "trick" FreeMarker into loading a template with an ad-hoc `setDirectoryForTemplateLoading` and such.)

Comment: I am creating the Configuration object only once, this was shown here like that to try and simplify what I'm trying to do. I suppose that to narrow down my question will be: How do I use Spring Resource file as a Templete in freemarker

Comment: As far as I see, in Spring you have a `ResourceLoader` which can resolve Resource strings to `Resource` objects. So you should implement a `TemplateLoader` that delegates to a `ResourceLoader`. (Unless the Spring FreeMarker support already implements that, of course.) Then use `cfg.setTemplateLoader(yourResourceTemplateLoader)`.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid from developing my own TemplateLoader. Surely there is a way to tell Freemarker to load templates from the classpath?

Comment: There is, but Spring Resource strings aren't always starting with "classpath:", plus who knows what `ClassLoader`-s Spring uses. So my guess is still that the simplest and cleanest thing is just to go ahead and wrap a `ResourceLoader` into `TemplateLoader` interface. Maybe you have already spent more time with finding a workaround than what the clean solution would take.