# Load freemarker template from classpath

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I have a Resource in aSpring MVCapplication loaded from the classpath.

```
<bean id="myController" class="com.MyController">
        <property name="myTemplate" value="classpath:myTemplate.txt"/>

</bean>
```

And I am trying to load it as a freemarker Template using this code:

```
private Resource myTemplate;

...

Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/");
Template tpl = cfg.getTemplate(myResource.getFilename());
```

But I keep ending up in: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template classpath:myTemplate.txt not found.

I tried implementing what wassuggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019424/setting-freemarker-template-from-classpath) however it doesn't seem to help.

The only hack I could findso far was to remove the "classpath: prefix from the filename String but I prefer not to do it

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you are saying is that you don't want to remove `"class:"` from the template name, and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671464) you don't want to teach FreeMarker understanding it via a custom `TemplateLoader` either. I mean, if you bar these, what else could possibly solve this? I can only advice you to do the last; implement a  custom `TemplateLoader` (either one that just removes the `"class:"` prefix then delegates to `ClassTemplateLoader`, or, even better, one that just delegates to a Spring `ResourceLoader`). That's how you configure FreeMarker to do what you want. It's not something extreme to do, implementing your own `TemplateLoader`.

**Update:** It might by useful to know that *by default* there's a mismatch between the FreeMarker template name syntax and Spring's resource name syntax. According the Spring syntax, you can write `"classpath:foo.ftl"` or `"classpath:/foo.ftl"`. But FreeMarker assumes that the scheme part always ends with `://`, and a lonely `:` or `:/` is nothing special. So all these resource paths will be seen as relative paths, and so the current template directory will be prepended before them before the actual template resolution. To solve this, since FreeMarker 2.3.22, you can use `Configuration.setTemplateNameFormat(TemplateNameFormat.DEFAULT_2_4_0)` (`template_name_format=DEFAULT_2_4_0` in `Properties`), which does consider `:` as scheme separator.